# Recursion forEach does not update my values? using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to update my values with recursion but my loop no work?
First check code:

```
  const minusItem = (items) => {
    console.log("items", items);
    if (items.length > 0) {
      items.forEach((orgUnit) => {
        orgUnit.dashCheck = true;
        orgUnit.allChildItemChecked = false;
        if (orgUnit.parentNode.unitId) {
          minusItem(orgUnit.parentNode); //recursion
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

items is array but worst of all sometimes an object is sent but there is an if that says

items.length > 0

here I filter only strings that have length> 0

array is like

```
[
 { 
 unitId: 1 ,
 title: "Test 1 " ,
 dashCheck: false,
 allChildItemChecked: false
 parentNode: {
    unitId: 2 ,
    title: "Test 2" ,
    dashCheck: false,
    allChildItemChecked: false, 
    parentNode: { 
       unitId: 3 ,
       title: "Test 3" ,
       dashCheck: false,
       allChildItemChecked: false, 
        }
      } 
   }
]
```

of these parentNode can have 100....

I need to loop thought each and set

```
    orgUnit.dashCheck = true;
    orgUnit.allChildItemChecked = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

You only have **one** array. The nested objects are not arrays, so they don't have a `length` property.

The `forEach` should be moved outside of the recursive function, where it will execute only once:

```js
const minusItem = (item) => {
    item.dashCheck = true;
    item.allChildItemChecked = false;
    if (item.parentNode) { // Just check if there is a parent node
        minusItem(item.parentNode); //recursion 
    }
};

let data = [{ 
 unitId: 1 ,
 title: "Test 1 " ,
 dashCheck: false,
 allChildItemChecked: false,
 parentNode: {
    unitId: 2 ,
    title: "Test 2" ,
    dashCheck: false,
    allChildItemChecked: false, 
    parentNode: { 
       unitId: 3 ,
       title: "Test 3" ,
       dashCheck: false,
       allChildItemChecked: false, 
    }
  } 
}];

data.forEach(minusItem); // The only place to perform a loop
console.log(data);
```

### Moving the iteration inside a function:

If you need the main function to be `minusItem` **and** to be called on the original *array*, then make a second function for the recursive part:

```js
const minusItem = (items) => items.forEach(minusItemRecur);

const minusItemRecur = (item) => {
    item.dashCheck = true;
    item.allChildItemChecked = false;
    if (item.parentNode) { // Just check if there is a parent node
        minusItemRecur(item.parentNode); //recursion 
    }
};

let data = [{ 
 unitId: 1 ,
 title: "Test 1 " ,
 dashCheck: false,
 allChildItemChecked: false,
 parentNode: {
    unitId: 2 ,
    title: "Test 2" ,
    dashCheck: false,
    allChildItemChecked: false, 
    parentNode: { 
       unitId: 3 ,
       title: "Test 3" ,
       dashCheck: false,
       allChildItemChecked: false, 
    }
  } 
}];

minusItem(data);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Is possible to data.forEach (minusItem); not calling? Because it creates some other problems for me so i would just like to pass the value and within the minusItem function changes are happening

Comment: No, you'll have to iterate. You can of course wrap that part in yet another function. I don't see the problem. Added an alternative to my answer with a second function

Answer (score 1):

**Lodash** [cloneDeepWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeepWith) if you don't mind

```js
const data = [{unitId: 1 ,title:"Test 1 ",dashCheck: false,allChildItemChecked:false,parentNode:{unitId:2,title:"Test 2" ,dashCheck:false,allChildItemChecked:false,parentNode:{unitId:3 ,title:"Test 3",dashCheck:false,allChildItemChecked:false}}}];

const result = _.cloneDeepWith(data, (val, key) => {
    if (key === 'dashCheck') return true;
    if (key === 'allChildItemChecked') return false;       
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```